# How should I access data about the array used to populate a tableview with RxSwift and MVVM

Tags: swift, mvvm, rx-swift

I'm trying to learn MVVM and RxSwift by making a messaging app, but can't figure out the best way to style cells based on details of the previous cell and if it is the latest cell in the table view. These are used to determine if it has a tail and shows the date above the message.

Currently the `messageHasTail()` and `messageShowsDate()` functions get an array with all the messages on it.

Also what improvements can be made to the structure.

TableViewControl

```
let appServerClient = AppServerClient()
let conversationVM:ConversationViewModel
let messages = [Message]()

init( ) {
    self.inputBar = InputBarAccessoryView()
    conversationVM = ConversationViewModel(appServerClient)
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
...
bindViewModel()
conversationVM.getMessages()
}

func bindViewModel(){

    conversationVM.text.asObservable()
        .bind(to: inputBar.inputTextView.rx.text)
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)


    inputBar.inputTextView.rx.text.compactMap { $0 }
    .bind(to: conversationVM.text)
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)

    inputBar.sendButton.rx.tap.asObservable()
        .bind(to: conversationVM.submitButtonTapped)
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)


    conversationVM.conversationOb.bind(to: self.tableView.rx.items) { tableView, index, message in

        let indexPath = IndexPath(item: index, section: 0)
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "messageCell", for: indexPath) as? MessageCell else {
                       return UITableViewCell()
                   }
        cell.isOutgoing = self.appServerClient.currentUser.id == message.user.id
        cell.hasTail = self.messageHasTail(i: index)
        cell.hasDate = self.messageShowsDate(i: index)
        cell.message = message
      //  self.animateSendMessage()

        return cell

           }.disposed(by: disposeBag)

}
```

ConversationViewModel

```
class ConversationViewModel {

    let appServerClient:AppServerClient
  //  var conversation: Conversation

    var conversationOb:  Observable<[Message]>{
        return cells.asObservable()
    }
    var text = BehaviorRelay<String>(value:"")
    let submitButtonTapped = PublishSubject<Void>()

     let cells : BehaviorRelay<[Message]>
    let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    init(_ appServerClient: AppServerClient) {

        cells = BehaviorRelay<[Message]>(value:[])

        self.appServerClient = appServerClient


        submitButtonTapped
        .subscribe(
            onNext: { [weak self] in
                self?.postMessage()
            }
        )
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }

    func getMessages() {
        appServerClient
            .getMessages()
            .subscribe(
                onNext: { [weak self] messages in
                    //empty and error removed
                    self?.cells.accept(messages)
                }
            )
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }

    func postMessage(){
        appServerClient.postMessage(text: text.value)
        getMessages()
    }

}
```

MessageCell

```
class MessageCell: UITableViewCell {

    var hasTail = true {
        didSet {
            messageBubble.hasTail  = self.hasTail
            bottomConstraint.constant = (hasTail ? vertGapPad : 0)
        }
    }

    var hasDate = true {
        didSet {
            self.dateLabel.text = Date.dateMessageString(date: message.date)
            hideDateConstraint.isActive = !hasDate
            topConstraint.constant = (hasDate ? vertGapPad : 0)
        }
    }

    var message = Message() {
        didSet {
            messageLabel.text = message.text
        }
    }
    var isOutgoing = true {
        didSet {...
```

Answer (score 1):

#### I will suggest you to use protocols for data manipulating

## MessageCellProtocol

`Message` must implement `MessageCellProtocol`

```
protocol MessageCellProtocol {
    var hasTail: Bool { get }
    var hasDate: Bool { get }
    var message: String { get set }
    var date: Date { get set }
    var isOutgoing: Bool { get }
}
```

## ViewModel

```
final class ConversationViewModel {
    private let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    private let appServerClient: AppServerClient
    // 1
    let sendTrigger = PublishSubject<String>()
    // 2
    let getTrigger = PublishSubject<Void>()
    // 3
    let messages = BehaviorRelay<[Message]>(value [])

    init(_ appServerClient: AppServerClient) {
        self.appServerClient = appServerClient

        sendTrigger
            // 4
            .filter { !$0.isEmpty }
            // 5
            .map(appServerClient.postMessage)
            // 6
            .bind(to: getTrigger)
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)

        getTrigger
            // 7
            .flatMap { appServerClient.getMessages() }
            // 8
            .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
            // 9
            .bind(to: messages)
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }

}
```

1. Subject for sending message
2. Subject for getting all messages
3. Relay for messages response
4. Allows sending when message is not empty string
5. Sends message to server
6. Binds to getTrigger for getting messages after sending
7. Request for getting messages
8. Switch response's Queue to MainQueue after doing request
9. Binds to messages relay

## MessageCell

```
final class MessageCell: UITableViewCell {
    private (set) var message: MessageCellProtocol!

    func render(_ message: MessageCellProtocol) {
        self.message = message

        messageBubble.hasTail = message.hasTile
        bottomConstraint.constant = (message.hasTile ? vertGapPad : 0)

        self.dateLabel.text = Date.dateMessageString(date: message.date)    
        hideDateConstraint.isActive = !message.hasDate
        topConstraint.constant = (message.hasDate ? vertGapPad : 0)

        messageLabel.text = message.text

        ...
    }
```

## ViewController

```
let appServerClient = AppServerClient()
let viewModel: ConversationViewModel

let messages = BehaviorRelay<[Message]>(value [])

init() {
    self.inputBar = InputBarAccessoryView()
    conversationVM = ConversationViewModel(appServerClient)
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ...
    setupTableView()
    doBindings()
}

override func viewDidAppear() {
    super.viewDidAppear()
    viewModel.getTrigger.onNext(())
}

func doBindings() {
    inputBar
        .sendButton
        .rx.tap
        .withLatestFrom(inputBar.inputTextView.rx.text.orEmpty)
        .bind(to: viewModel.sendTrigger)
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)

    viewModel.messages
        .bind(to: messages)
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
}

func setupTableView() {
    messages
         .bind(to: tableView.rx.items) { (tv, _, message) in
             guard let cell = tv.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "messageCell") as? MessageCell else { return UITableVIewCell() }
             cell.render(message)
             return cell
         }
         .disposed(by: disposeBag)
}
```

Comment: Hi Yervand, thanks for the reply. I am unable to bind the viewmodel messages to the view controller messages as one is has type Message and one has type MessageProtocol

Comment: Yes it's true. you have two ways to cast `Message` to `PessageCellProtocol`
change `let messages = BehaviorRelay<[MessageCellProtocol]>(value [])` to `let messages = BehaviorRelay<[Message]>(value [])` or 
`viewModel.messages.bind(to: messages) .disposed(by: disposeBag)` to `viewModel.messages.map { $0.compactMap { $0 as? MessageCellProtocol } } .bind(to: messages) .disposed(by: disposeBag)`. I'll update post